# Category with pullbacks but not equalizers

Tags: category-theory

Is there an example of a category with pullbacks but not equalizers (i.e. at least one pair of parallel morphisms does not have an equalizer)?

Such a category cannot have have the terminal object, it cannot have binary products, there must exist morphisms $f, g$ such that there is no upper bound $u$ such that $u \circ f = u \circ g$, [as shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350138/coequalizerspullbacks-implies-equalizers).

If possible, the example should not be constructed for this purpose.

Comment: At a guess, I would say $\mathbf{LH}$, the category of topological spaces and local homeomorphisms.

Comment: Or a group, considered as a category with one object.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: @AlešBizjak OK, I will do. I always intended to post it as an answer, but thought I'd wait a few hours to avoid discouraging people from posting other enlightening examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a non-trivial group. There is a standard way to regard $G$ as a category with one object, where $G$ is the set of morphisms, and composition is given by the group operation.

Let $g,h\in G$ with $g\neq h$. Then $g$ and $h$ have no equalizer, since there is no element $x\in G$ with $gx=hx$.

But the pullback of $(g,h)$ does exist, given by the pair of elements/morphisms $(g^{-1},h^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a set, the discrete category $Disc(S)$ has all pullbacks. If the cardinality of $S$ is not $1$ then $Disc(S)$ does not have a terminal object.

Comment: But it does have equalizers, doesn’t it?